# Rewrite code using promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timeout, promise

I have the following code that causes the two call to Webtrends to be cancelled (ie these two calls did not give a http 200 but a cancelled message in the network tab of the browser) when I call it

```
mercury.Tracking.logUsage("export", GetSelectedExportType(form));
mercury.Tracking.logUsage('exportchart', mercury.ChartContainer.currentChartUri(), path);
form[0].submit();
```

I rewrote this in this way to avoid this issue, as it seemed to me that the reason why the calls to Webtrends were being cancelled was because the form submit was making that happen so before calling submit on the form I wait two seconds.

```
mercury.Tracking.logUsage("export", GetSelectedExportType(form));
mercury.Tracking.logUsage('exportchart', mercury.ChartContainer.currentChartUri(), path);

var submit = function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    form[0].submit();
  }, 2000);
};
submit();
```

Question is, is there a better way, using promises or callbacks or whatever to do this?

The logUsage code is

```
(function ($, window) {
    function Tracking() {

    }

    Tracking.prototype.chartTitle = function () {
        return $('#chartNameInfo').text();
    };

    Tracking.prototype.hostName = function () {
        return $('#trackingVars').data('host-name');
    };

    Tracking.prototype.page = function () {
        return $('#trackingVars').data('page');
    };

    Tracking.prototype.currentUser = function () {
        return window.config.userId;
    };

    Tracking.prototype.logUsage = function (action, resourceUri, actionTargetUri, additionalTags) {
        // action: action performed - e.g. create, delete, export
        // resourceUri:  URI of API resource *on* which action is being performed (required), e.g. /users/current/annotations/{annotation-id}
        // actionTargetUri: URI of API resource *to* which action is being performed (optional), e.g. /charts/{chart-id}

        if (action.indexOf("DCSext.") < 0) {
            action = "DCSext." + action;
        }

        var jsonString = '{"' + action + '"' + ':"1"}';
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        if (additionalTags == null) {
            additionalTags = jsonObj;
        }
        else {
            additionalTags = $.extend({}, additionalTags, jsonObj); //Append two JSON objects
        }

        var trackingargs = $.extend({
            'DCSext.resource-uri': resourceUri,
            'DCSext.action-target-uri': actionTargetUri,
            'WT.ti': this.chartTitle(),
            'DCSext.dcssip': this.hostName(),
            'DCSext.em-user-id': this.currentUser(),
            dsci_uri: this.page()
        }, additionalTags);
        try {
            WebTrends.multiTrack({ args: trackingargs });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    window.Tracking = new Tracking();

    $(function() {
        $('body').on('click', 'a[data-tracking-action]', function() {
            window.Tracking.logUsage($(this).data('tracking-action'), $(this).data('tracking-resource'));
        });

        $(document).on('attempted-access-to-restricted-resource', function(event, href) {
            window.Tracking.logUsage('unauthorisedResourceAccessUpsell', href.url);
        });
    });

})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: So you need to submit only once both .logUsage calls are completed?
Also, does that method accept a callback function once the logging is done?

Comment: yes for the first question and no for the second.

Comment: Can you post `mercury.Tracking.logUsage`'s code please ?

Comment: I was more interested in what your logUsage method does, not so much the definition. Can you post the full code?

Comment: @AntoineCloutier here's the complete code.

Comment: I provided an answer, let me know if it's any help.

Comment: Why are you saving all your data in the DOM? Also where are your promises and your current attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trying to steal Antoine's rep. His answer is essentially fine, but the `...` sections can be fleshed out far more efficiently than in the question, plus a few other points for consideration.

```
Tracking.prototype.logUsage = function (action, resourceUri, actionTargetUri, additionalTags) {
    // action: action performed - e.g. create, delete, export
    // resourceUri:  URI of API resource *on* which action is being performed (required), e.g. /users/current/annotations/{annotation-id}
    // actionTargetUri: URI of API resource *to* which action is being performed (optional), e.g. /charts/{chart-id}

    try { 
        // you might as well wrap all the preamble in the try{}, just in case it it error-prone

        if (action.indexOf("DCSext.") < 0) {
            action = "DCSext." + action;
        }

        //trackingargs can be defined efficiently as follows, avoiding the need for the variable `jsonObj` and the ugly JSON.parse().
        var trackingargs = $.extend({
            'DCSext.resource-uri': resourceUri,
            'DCSext.action-target-uri': actionTargetUri,
            'WT.ti': this.chartTitle(),
            'DCSext.dcssip': this.hostName(),
            'DCSext.em-user-id': this.currentUser(),
            'dsci_uri': this.page()
        }, additionalTags || {}); // `additionalTags || {}` caters for missing or null additionalTags

        trackingargs[action] = 1;//associative syntax gets around the limitation of object literals (and avoids the need for JSON.parse()!!!).

        //to keep things tidy, return $.Deferred(fn).promise()
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            WebTrends.multiTrack({
                args: trackingargs,
                finish: dfrd.resolve //no need for another function wrapper. `$.Deferred().resolve` and `$.Deferred().reject` are "detachable"
            });
        }).promise();//be sure to return a promise, not the entire Deferred.

    } catch (e) {

        console.log(e);

        //Now, you should really ensure that a rejected promise is always returned.
        return $.Deferred.reject(e).promise();//Surrogate re-throw.

    }
};
```

*see comments in code*

As `Tracking.prototype.logUsage` can now return a rejected promise, and as you probably don't want `.logUsage()` failure to inhibit your form submission, you probably want to convert rejected promises to fulfilled.

```
$.when(
    mercury.Tracking.logUsage("export", GetSelectedExportType(form)).then(null, function() {
        return $.when();//resolved promise
    }),
    mercury.Tracking.logUsage('exportchart', mercury.ChartContainer.currentChartUri(), path).then(null, function() {
        return $.when();//resolved promise
    })
).done(function() {
    form[0].submit(); 
});
```

It may seem to be an unnecessary complication to return a rejected promise then convert to success, however :

- it is good practice to report asycnhronous failure in the form of a rejected promise, not simply log the error and return undefined.
- `window.Tracking.logUsage()` may be called elsewhere in your code, where it is necessary to handle an error as an error.

Comment: I tried all this but it still comes out as cancelled.

Comment: No worries about "stealing" my rep, I stil have a lot to learn :).
In fact, I am not sure I understand the part where you convert rejected promises. From my understanding, rejected promises will trigger the `.fail()` callback while resolved promises will trigger the `.done()` callback.

Comment: They both are great answers, which is why I've +1ed both of them.  But they both don't work.  Perhaps it's something I'm doing wrong - not sure what - followed all steps exactly.

Comment: @SachinKainth It's hard to say. Do you have a public site where would could observe the problem ?

Comment: @AntoineCloutier Unfortunately not.

Comment: @AntoineCloutier Having put in alerts into the code as shown above I get the output: finished, finished, done.  The other alerts don't get called!

Comment: @SachinKainth That is Roamer's code. I would say that the output is as expected, deferred #1 resolved, deferred #2 resolved, `.done()` callback. I am not sure what isn't working for you, but I don't think it has anything to do with your `.multiTrack()` being asynchronous, as we have added deferreds. Perhaps try the `callback` property instead of `finish` ?

Comment: Yes, my overall approach is taken directly from @AntoineCloutier 's answer. I've just fleshed it out with code from the question and tidied it up. I haven't tried to verify whether or not {..., 'finish':fn} is correct. Maybe that's the next thing to check.

Comment: I'm busy for the next few hours. Will check back later.

Comment: Do the "finished" alerts happen?

Comment: I have never worked with the WebTrending library he is using, I just assumed from the Docs that the `finish` event was what he was looking for. I think using the `callback` event will solve the issue.

Comment: Yup, `callback` is certainly a cool thing to try. I was hoping that Sachin might be able to say whether the alerts happen. That would assist in knowing if `finished` or `callback` (or `complete` ...) is the correct option.

Comment: Sachin, I understand that you might want to try different things, but why edit my answer? As it stood, it was no longer my answer so I rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

With the extra information provided, I think I can now answer your question.

From [WebTrends doc](http://help.webtrends.com/en/jstag/tracking_mulitrack_advanced.html), you can add a finish callback to your WebTrends.MultiTrack call.
What you could do:

```
Tracking.prototype.logUsage = function (action, resourceUri, actionTargetUri, additionalTags) {
  ...
  var finished = $.Deferred();
  ...
  try {
    WebTrends.multiTrack({ args: trackingargs, finish: function(){finished.resolve();}});
  }
  ...
  return finished;
}
```

and then in your code:

```
$.when(mercury.Tracking.logUsage("export", GetSelectedExportType(form)),
mercury.Tracking.logUsage('exportchart', mercury.ChartContainer.currentChartUri(), path))
  .done(function(){
    form[0].submit(); 
  });
```

I have not tested this, but I think it should work. Hope it helps.

Explanations:

[jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one
>   or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous
>   events.

Basically, jQuery.when() will take one or more deferreds (which build promises) or promises and will return one promise that fulfills when they all fulfill. From there, we can choose to add handlers using th e [.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) method to our promise, which will be called once or promise is fulfilled . (A promise represents the result of an asynchronous operation).

So, in the code above, I created a new deferred object in your `logUsage` method, and that method returns the deferred, so you can pass those deferreds to `jQuery.when` method and when they will be fulfilled (this is why I added the finish callback in your `WebTrends.Multitrack` call), the handler passed to `deferred.done()` will be executed.

I hope this is not too confusing, I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly.

Comment: This looks like the start of a good answer explaining a correct conversion - it's best to explain how and why it works though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Added some explanations, feel free to edit my post!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I still get cancelled calls in the browser.